# How re recreate project linkages from decompiled JAR using JD-GUI?

Tags: java, decompiler, jd-gui

I have a legacy .JAR file. I am able to de-compile it with JD-GUI, but this gives me a set of class files. I am trying to follow code through but there is limited linkage between the various classes.

I can follow the code manually, but is there a way to "re link" or create a project, so that I can navigate more easily.

JD-GUI does this partly when it underlines certain classes, but only takes me to the class. I would like to go direct to a declaration or see all usages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want options similar to eclipse `Goto` references and declarations etc.

- Open JD-GUI and JAR file from it
- Select Save All sources option it will create zip file with source
- Now extract the zip into a folder
- Open eclipse and create java project.
- Copy the extracted content and paste it in `src` folder in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

To work more effective you can do the following.

- Open Eclipse IDE, press CTRL + N, choose the option Java Project.

[image]

- Unchecked the option **Default Location**, search the project folder decompiled

[image]

- Choose the project, checked the option **Default Option** again and finish the Wizard.

[image]

With this steps you will ready to work.